# Tensorflow doesnt generate pb file.How Solve it?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, image-recognition

I am using Tensorflow Image Recognition Trainer. But I cant get .pb and .txt files of training. I cant find them. When I add flag "--output-graph" it doesnt create any file. There is not any problem with permission of folder. I dont know how solve it.

Project is in docker.

What Tutorials I use:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining
https://petewarden.com/2016/02/28/tensorflow-for-poets/

Answer (score -1):

I found the reason of this problem. There was the problem with number of images for training. There must be 20 images in each direction of class.